# How do I get the array value in the array list using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements

I am trying get the array value from the array list by creating a local variable called weight. for example, float weight = weights[i];
Every time it loops back it should assign the array value to weights. But when I run it in vocareum, it's not working. Any advice would help!

```
public class CheckoutMachine {

float calculateWeight(float[] weights, boolean hasLoyaltyCard) {
     float totalWeight = 0f;
     // TODO: Step 1 work goes between the two comments
     for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
         float weight = weights[i];
         if (weight < 20 && hasLoyaltyCard == true) {
             weight *= 0.95;
             totalWeight = weight + totalWeight;
         }
     }
    
    //
    return totalWeight;
}
```

Error output:

```
ddd_v1_w_lel_1459701@runweb63415:~$ run-workflow step-01                                                                                                              
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                      
> Task :test FAILED                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                      
CheckoutMachineTest > calculateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float) > com.ata.Che                                                                                      
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <60.0> but was: <0.0>                                                                                              
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                                                                                          
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:102                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:97)                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:714)                                                                                         
        at com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calculateWeightTest(CheckoutMachineTest.j                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                      
CheckoutMachineTest > calculateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float) > com.ata.Che                                                                                      
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <59.05> but was: <18.05>                                                                                           
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                                                                                          
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:102                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:97)                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:714)                                                                                         
        at com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calculateWeightTest(CheckoutMachineTest.j                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                      
CheckoutMachineTest > calculateWeightTest(float[], boolean, float) > com.ata.Che                                                                                      
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <19.0> but was: <0.0>                                                                                              
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)                                                                                          
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:102                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:97)                                                                                      
        at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:714)                                                                                         
        at com.ata.CheckoutMachineTest.calculateWeightTest(CheckoutMachineTest.j                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                      
4 tests completed, 3 failed                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                      
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here are the instructions, given, I read it over many times and hit a brick wall when it came to solving this error.

```
Create a for loop that goes through the whole weights array.
Within the for loop, do the following:
Create a local variable of type float called weight to store the value of weights at a specific index.
Create a conditional that checks whether weight is under 20 and whether hasLoyaltyCard is true and multiple weight by 0.95 if it is.
Add weight to totalWeight the variable.
```

Comment: `&& hasLoyaltyCard == true` should better to  use `&& hasLoyaltyCard` instead,and seems you need to put `totalWeight = weight + totalWeight` outside `if`

Comment: *"But when I run it in vocareum, it's not working"* - so.. call me dumb, but what is this vocareum? do they have some kind web-based java compiler or something?

Comment: thing is, i take a look on your code and still can't find whats wrong. i took your code to jdoodle (online java compiler) and it works just fine. thats why i suspect something with the platform (that vocareum) might be the cause, not java itself.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @BagusTesa They don't compile my code, they give me a set of instructions of what to do then afterwards run a check on it using a bash command. It'll give two outputs build successful or build failed.

Comment: @francoisvang what error message did you get when it refuse to compile? can you add that information into the question?

Comment: @francoisvang so, yeah, the `test` unit failed not the build (or compile). figures. so, its not the "loop" failed but you had trouble implementing the exam. do we know the input and expected output of the program?

Comment: *"Create a conditional that checks whether weight is under 20 and whether `hasLoyaltyCard` is true and multiple weight by 0.95 if it is."* - i think this run-on sentence might cause some confusion. it seems you need to keep adding `totalWeight` regardless of its value. however if current `weight` is under 20 and `hasLoyaltyCard` is `true` **then** multiply it by 0.95. but without input and expected output, its just a guesswork.

Comment: @BagusTesa That's the same sentence that confused me. But I believe it's asking me to get assign `weight` to match the value of the array given each time the statement loops. Then create an if statement that will apply a 5% discount to the total weight.  Since weight carries the total weight already. The program is asking to assign it to another variable. I am making sure I understand the purpose of this assignment and seeing if I missed something.

Comment: @francoisvang do the exam provide sample input with it's expected output? just to make sure we are reading things right.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments from your question, let me provide some clarification: it is asking you to add every weight in the array to `totalWeight`, but (before adding the weight) if the weight in at a certain index is `< 20 && hasLoyaltyCard` then you give a 5% discount (or `weight * 0.95`).

With that being clarified, you nearly have the right answer, but your placement of a variable to be updated is a bit off.. The if statement should be for adjusting only the `weight` variable, if needed. Anything else (in this case) should be under the loop code block. I hope this helps direct you to the right answer!

Also, one more thing you can do to make your code shorter/cleaner is using `+=` to add `weight` to the `totalWeight`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
int i;

for (i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    float weight = weights[i]; 
    if (weight < 20 && hasLoyaltyCard) {
        weight *= 0.95;
    } 
    totalWeight += weight;
}
return totalWeight;
```